# How to get a button's current image using imageForState?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

I found a property called imageForState in xcode but am having trouble getting it to do what I want. When a button is pressed, I want to execute a block of code depending on the button's image.

```
- (IBAction)favButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *currentImage = [sender imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if([currentImage isEqualToString:@"already_fav"])
    {
        // execute code
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing NSString _strong with an expression type of UIImage
```

Can someone please tell how to get around this?

Comment: read carefully..the error explains everything :)..and you should also give a second look on method naming..they are super descriptive in obj C

Comment: I understand the error message, but am wondering how to get the current displayed image's name as a string value, obviously my code isn't working as it is comparing apples to oranges

Comment: Instead of creating a UIImage object, is there some way to just a string of the filename that is used to display the image?

Comment: you can't get string value..you should either compare the image with a another instance of same image...or use subclass/other way to solve your query

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am sure that you are not able to compare a string with an image. There is a solution however. All you have to do is set the tag for the image you are wanting to compare, and set the tag of the image you are comparing to.

```
 image1.tag = 1;
 image.tag =1;

 if(image1.tag == image.tag) {
      // execute code
 }
```

that should help, and I hope that it does.

SO, for this exercise, i'll show you. Change the NSString to a UIImage

```
 UIImage *currentImage = [sender imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];

 currentImage.tag = 1;
 wantedImage.tag = 1;

if(currentImage.tag == wantedImage.tag) {
   // do something
}
```

hopefully this helps you out :)

Answer (score 4):

When you create a UIImage it is just an image and has no string value attached. The name is not carried by the UIImage object.

If it were me (and this isn't the only solution, just another suggestion), i'd create individual UIImage objects (depending on how many we're talking about here) as this should checkable while strings are not.

For example:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"randomName"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anotherRandomName"];
[myButton setImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
if ([myButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] == image1) {
    NSLog(@"The button shows image 1 for normal state");
}
else if ([myButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] == image2) {
    NSLog(@"The button shows image 2 for normal state");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error!!!!!!! :D");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you cant save the Image as a String

try

`UIImage *currentImage = [sender imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];`

than you can check:

`if(currentImage  == [UIImage imageNamed:@"already_fav"])`

Answer (score 2):

I did this for switching sound/noSound image on button:

```
- (IBAction)soundAction:(id)sender {
    UIImage *sound = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sound"];
    UIImage *noSound = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noSound"];

    if ([[sender currentImage] isEqual:sound]) {
        NSLog(@"IF SOUND IMAGE");
        [sender setImage:noSound forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //your code
    } else if([[sender currentImage] isEqual:noSound]) {
        NSLog(@"IF NO SOUND IMAGE");
        [sender setImage:sound forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //your code
    }
}
```